# Data extraction in for loop using r

Tags: r, quantmod

I am trying to find and compare daily gain and loss percentage in two stocks in r. This is the code

```
library(quantmod) 
stockData <- new.env() #Make a new environment for quantmod to store data in
tickers <- c("AAPL","GOOG") 
#Set start date
start_date=as.Date("2014-01-01")
getSymbols(tickers, src="yahoo", env=stockData,from=start_date)
for (tick in tickers) {
  x <- get(tick, pos=stockData)  # get data from stockData environment  
  x$gl<-((Cl(x)-Op(x))/Op(x))*100 #Daily gain loss percentage
}
```

I am able to calculate daily gain/loss percentage for individual stocks but I don't know how to proceed further and extract-compare gain/loss percentage of multiple stocks separately.

Example

```
if AAPL(gain/loss percentage) is greater than GOOG(gain/loss percentage) then 1 else -1
```

Comment: Do you need a `for loop`? Why not individually extract data and then compare g/l: `applx <- get("APPL", pos=stockData)` and `googlex <-get("GOOG", pos=stockData)`?

Comment: @Parfait I think for two stocks loop is not needed but I am also considering adding multiple stocks(say 5 or 15) then in my opinion for automation looping is a better way to do it

Comment: but which two stocks would you then compare for g/l if you expand to multiple stocks? All possible two-pair permutations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a good starting point. However, I would suggest that you store the data of the tickers in a list. As the code is now, only the data of the last ticker treated in the loop is stored in `x`.

This slightly modified version might help:

```
library(quantmod) 
stockData <- new.env() #Make a new environment for quantmod to store data in
tickers <- c("AAPL","GOOG","YHOO","FB") 
#Set start date
start_date <- as.Date("2014-01-01")
getSymbols(tickers, src="yahoo", env=stockData, from=start_date)
x <- list()
for (i in 1:length(tickers)) {
  x[[i]] <- get(tickers[i], pos=stockData)  # get data from stockData environment  
  x[[i]]$gl <-((Cl(x[[i]])-Op(x[[i]]))/Op(x[[i]]))*100 #Daily gain loss percentage
}
compare_pl <- function(x,y){ifelse(x$gl > y$gl, 1, -1)}
aapl_vs_goog <- compare_pl(x[[1]],x[[2]])
```

Now the variable `aapl_vs_goog` contains the data on the days where AAPL outperformed GOOG (`+1`) or vice versa (`-1`):

```
> tail(aapl_vs_goog)
#           gl
#2015-08-19 -1
#2015-08-20  1
#2015-08-21  1
#2015-08-24  1
#2015-08-25 -1
#2015-08-26 -1
```

Needless to say that this can be performed in the same way for any other ticker.

Comment: Somewhat unrelated to your question, I think that your definition of the percent value of daily gain and loss is unusual. The daily gain in percent is typically calculated by taking the difference between the close of one day and the close of the previous day (and not the open of the same day), divided by the close of the previous day. You may want to change this part of the code.